# How to guarantee only a value exists between two nullable column in a table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

`user` have two FK, one to `student` and second one to `teacher`, both nullable.

```sql
create table user(
  employeeId int null,
  teacherId  int null
  foreign key (employeeId) references employee (id),
  foreign key (teacherId) references teacher (id)
);
```

I need that when `employeeId` is null, `teacherId` must exist, and when `employeeId` exists, `teacherId` must be null.

Never both null or both existent. Is there any way to guarantee this behaviour during table creation?

Class table inheritance don't suit my case.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  You will probably need to create a trigger to handle this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use CHECK (MySQL 8.0.16+):

```
create table user(
  employeeId int null,
  teacherId  int null,
  foreign key (employeeId) references employee (id),
  foreign key (teacherId) references teacher (id),
  CHECK ((employeeId IS NULL) + (teacherId IS NULL) = 1)
);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=160e5df317abb19485494742166fcf10)**

---

```
CREATE TABLE employee(id INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(1);

CREATE TABLE teacher(id INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO teacher VALUES(1);

create table user(
  employeeId int null,
  teacherId  int null,
  foreign key (employeeId) references employee (id),
  foreign key (teacherId) references teacher (id),
  CHECK ((employeeId IS NULL) + (teacherId IS NULL) = 1)
);

INSERT INTO user VALUES(NULL,NULL);
-- Check constraint 'user_chk_1' is violated.

INSERT INTO user VALUES(1,1);
-- Check constraint 'user_chk_1' is violated.

INSERT INTO user VALUES(1,NULL);
INSERT INTO user VALUES(NULL,1);

SELECT * FROM user;
```

Comment: AFAIK check constraints won't work on MySQL versions earlier than 8+.  And also, your check constraint doesn't prevent _both_ foreign keys from being `NULL` at the same time.

Comment: To be exact - It's 8.0.16+

Comment: While this is not wrong, the correct boolean expression is `(employeeId IS NULL) XOR (teacherId IS NULL)`.

Comment: Thanks! How about the performance? Will the check impact negatively? If yes, does it impact only on insert operation?

Comment: @Chih It is simple CHECK constraint on row level and the expression is simple so the impact on INSERT/UPDATE should be minimal

Comment: `CHECK` was implemented in MariaDB 10.2.1.